# QGIS -> Add VectorLayer DXF import fails: "invalid"

Tags: import, dxf, vector-layer

Trying to import a DXF file with Add VectorLayer is resulting in the error "not a valid or recognized data source."

Here is [the DXF file](http://be-lumino.us/files/brc-map-2014.dxf) that gives the error.  It is created by exporting from OpenSCAD.

However, I believe it's a valid file.  I am able import it in the Autodesk A360 Viewer. [Here it is in the viewer.](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/#id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTQ3ODI5MzA4ODg0NF8wMjMyNjEyMzExOTkyMDg2NDMuZHhm?designtype=)

I tried to use the DXF2SHP plugin, but subsequently read that it has been deprecated and is no longer maintained.

Any idea why this is failing?

Using QGIS 2.16.3

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your file. I opened your dxf file from `Add Vector Layer`  without problem using QGIS 2.14.8 and QGIS 2.18.0. Here is the output:

[image]

I also used the 'Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter' Plugin and it was opened without any problem. Here is the output also:

[image]

Try to use update your QGIS to the latest 2.18.0 or use QGIS 2.14.8 LTR (long term release). It may solve your problem.